# Paste multiple times in Vim

Tags: vim, copy-paste, paste

This maybe really simple, But I tried searching and I ended up with stuff like copying multiple lines, cut and paste multiple lines etc. What am looking for is pasting a single line multiple times in Vim.

For eg. A line 'X' is copied and I want to paste this line alone for say 30 times, thus I will have 30 'X' lines. Is it possible with a single command in Vim? Please help me.

Note: A single command for paste. Copy of the line can be done by 'y'. for pasting 30 times or so, I need a single command. Please help me here.

Answer (score 77, accepted):

Yes. Put before the command the number of times you want to repeat the action. And this works with many of `vim` commands. It would be:

```
30p
```

Answer (score 32):

In order to copy a line and paste it 30 times, first place the cursor on the line you want to copy, and then:

```
yy
30p
```

This will copy the line and paste it 30 times below it. If you want them in another place, then set the cursor to it, and do the `30p` part

Comment: Just to add, you need not limit yourself to a single line. You can copy a set of lines (for example using Visual Selection and then pressing `y`) and doing the paste operation x`p` times (where `x` is the number of times you want to paste, and `p` is the paste operation)

Answer (score 0):

Suppose you want to copy "n" lines and paste "m" times into the same file. Then open the file using Vim -

1. Move the cursor to the line from which you want to copy
2. If you want to copy 543 lines then enter `543yy` then you should observe `543 lines yanked` at the bottom of the Vim editor
3. To paste the lines 70 times then enter `70p`
4. To save the changes and quit the Vim editor then enter `:wq`